# How to send a select statement result (MySQL) from php to android using JSON?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm trying to get an array from an android app, this array is a `select` statement result but I can't get this array in android. I've tried with an array with simple numbers and it works but not with select result. I have ensured the select statement have items but it doesn't work.

this is the code in php:

```
<?php 
try {
    $gbd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tramites', $username,$password);

$categoria = $_POST['categoria'];

$stmt = $gbd->prepare("SELECT nombre, categoria FROM tramite WHERE categoria = :categ");
$result = $stmt->execute(array("categ"=>$categoria));
    $i=0;
$arreglo = array(); // arreglo para enviar
$result2 = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($result2 as $row)
{
    $arreglo[$i] = $row['nombre'].', '.$row['categoria'];
    $i++;
}

$gbd = null;
} 
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    print "¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

if($i >= 0)
{
    echo json_encode($arreglo);
}
?>
```

this code i´ts called from an android app and I need to receive the arregloarray in android but it returns null I don't know why.

My main code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings2) // JSON
    {
        String n="";
        HttpHandler handler= new HttpHandler();
        String txt=handler.getTramites2("tramites");
        n = parseProfilesJson(txt);
        Toast.makeText(this, "ca / "+ n+" /  "+ txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public String parseProfilesJson(String the_json)
{
     String res="";
    try {
         JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(the_json);

        JSONArray nameArray = myjson.names();
        JSONArray valArray = myjson.toJSONArray(nameArray);
        for(int i=0;i<valArray.length();i++)
        {
            String p = nameArray.getString(i) + "," + valArray.getString(i);
            res = res + p;
        }
        } catch (JSONException e)
        { e.printStackTrace(); }
     return res;
 }
```

and the class that is the HttpHandler:

```
public class HttpHandler
{
     protected String url = "http://192.168.43.98/tramitapue/";
     static String json = "";
     public String getTramites2(String categoria)
     {
       try{
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url+"getTramites2.php");
        //Parameter
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("categoria", categoria));

        // send parameters
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        // recibo paramteros
        //HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();

        ////////////////////////////////////
        // here i put json content
        // trace response
        InputStream is = resp.getEntity().getContent();
        //convert response to string
        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(myReader.readLine() + "\n");
        String line="";
        while ((line = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        json = sb.toString();
        ////////////////////////////////////

       //String text = EntityUtils.toString(ent);

        return json;
    }catch(Exception e){ return "Error en la Conexión " + e;}

}
```

**I don't get any error but I get a null value.** If I don't know if sql result have a different encode type. What´s wrong?

Comment: done any debugging, like checking how many rows your query retrieved, or if `categoria` was ever sent at all? as it stands right now, even if the query doesn't return anything, you script should still output an empty json array, e.g. `[]`

Comment: Is it possible the application is looking for a `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before your echo, so that it knows what kind of data is being returned to it?

Comment: I´ve tested and the select have at least one result.

Comment: which variable are you getting a null for?

Comment: I've solved. I got null in `$arreglo[$i] = $row['nombre'].', '.$row['categoria'];` but I just put this instead `$arreglo[$i] = utf8_encode($result['nombre']).', '.utf8_encode($result['categoria']);'. it works but when I put an accent put weird symbols instead of.

Comment: how can catch special symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my auto-response (if anyone serves this information).
I guess MySQL  statement give me a different encode type, so:
in ´foreach´ (php file) I added this:

```
        $arreglo[$i] = utf8_encode($result['nombre']).', '.utf8_encode($result['categoria']);
```

instead of the line that I have.

Answer (score 0):

Its sounds good that you have resolved your issue but as you told

**"I guess MySQL statement give me a different encode type, so:"**

Its better to set the database with utf-8 encoding which is accepted by android as well as the web rather encoding is programatically. Also you can remove all special characters before inserting it to the database for non buggy result.

Comment: Thanks! your first advice is a great idea but he second I dont think so, because I need the whole word included accent.